# Intellij sometimes not showing files

Tags: intellij-idea

Sometimes intellij just stops showing me certain files in the project pane.  They still exist on disk, and it still even leaves a gap for them, it just stops displaying the name (and double clicking on the empty space doesn't bring up the file).

I've tried synchronizing the packages and project, no luck.

In the image below, there is a LinuxSandboxStrategy file that should be "between" BUILD and LinuxSandboxWrapper. Another missing file can be seen under the skyframe package.

I'm using intellij community edition 2016.1 on Linux.

[image: Invisifiles.]

Comment: This happens for me on Win, usually when renaming files but only changing the casing for some letters and it's worse when using SVN, and I'm on IJ14 so it may take a while before they fix it... I don't think it matters if you're using Community Edition because I'm using Ultimate. The trick which solves it for me, is collapsing and then expanding the affected package. However I haven't figured why this actually happens and how it can be prevented/fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an old known bug (Feb 2014)... not fixed yet (July 2016)

Here is the related bug report : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-121164